# Perl program doesn't get displayed in browser (windows)

Tags: perl, xampp

system info: i have installed XAMPP on my machine having Window XP OS .

also installed Apache2.2,

now, i have created two folders in **C:\xampp\htdocs**  they are **php** and **perl** .

these folder contains programs in their respective languages (ie index.php and index.pl respectively)

when i type in browser :  http:   //localhost:88/php/  the program in index.php gets executed and o/p is displayed in browser

**but ,** when i type: http://localhost:88/perl/     browser displays a blank page

**PROBLEM  :**  how to run .pl file in above scenario ?

the code in index.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "<html>";
print "<h2>PERL</h2>";
print "this is text";
print "</html>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question has programmatic answer point is its not serverfault  question instead its stack overflow question

see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577161/multiple-perl-print-cgi-header-html-html-statement-gives-problem)

you'll know what i mean

Answer (score 0):

I think you gave us not enough information to properly identify the problem. What is the output of running index.pl outside the browser?

Comment: question is edited to give more info. pls check

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache config look for "DirectoryIndex". You will need to add index.pl to the list of files Apache will serve up if none is specified. Reload or restart Apache for the change to take effect.